Is there alternative methods to get the body for morgan middleware
This question is related to the question already posted here in stackoverflow 2 years ago, however I can't comment on the answers on that post so I'm going to ask the same question with my problem.
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require('dotenv').config()

const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const morgan = require('morgan')
const morganBody = require('morgan-body')
app.use(express.json())
morganBody(app)
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms :body'))

I used morgan as my middleware for logging and with the help of morgan-body library. I've noticed that when I try to reload the page after the data is initiated to the web, it returns an error but when I tried to post first the data using VS.rest(testing for REST http request) after the data was initiated then the logging middleware works fine.
This link is the post that is related to my mini project
I have modified my morgan 'tiny' and added the :body for the response to log.
More of my code on how I used the morgan.
app.get('/api/persons', (request, response) => {
    Person.find({})
    .then( phonebookData => {
        response.json(phonebookData)
        console.log(phonebookData)
    })
})

app.post('/api/persons', (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body
        person.save().then(savedPhonebook => {
        response.json(savedPhonebook)
    })

    morgan.token('body', request => {
        return JSON.stringify(request.body)
    })
})

I did try to find more answers but there's no question about this little problem(I think). I've only added the body on morgan and it behaves differently but I also understand since based on the documentation, there is no instruction adding it. I want to know why morgan behaves like this and if you know alternative solutions I don't need to add ':body' to my app.use(morgan())
